# Sending logs from fluentd to splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, multiline, fluentd, splunk-query

I am using log4j , so have different formats of logs. I am able to send most of the logs using the below multiline format from fluentd to splunk, but few of them behave differently(The logs with different date format).

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /tmp/LOG_SPLUNK.*
  pos_file /tmp/my-splunk.pos
  path_key log_type
  read_from_head true
  tag "splunk.#log.mylogs"
  format multiline
  format_firstline /^\[/
  format1 /\[(?<timestamp>[^ ]* [^ ]*)\] (?<level>[^ ]*) (?<message>.*)/
  time_type string
  time_key timestamp
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%N
  keep_time_key true
</source>
```

Below are logs formats:

```
[2022-04-13 06:27:08,340] INFO Loading plugin from: /my/path (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:380)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:355)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:261)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:253)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:222)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
[2022-04-13 06:27:09,520] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/my/path/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
Apr 13, 2022 6:27:17 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource will be ignored.
```

I am able to send all the above formats to splunk, but some behave differently. Is there any format using which i will be able to handle all. If i got a pattern not match error i could have included a format, but I don't

Comment: What do your different sourcetype props.conf files look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

[(?[^ ]* [^ ]*)] (?[^ ]*) (?[\W\w]+)

.* stops at a new line . [\W\w]+ will capture your whole stack trace in the message field.